# Query returns 0 rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a simple query to only select request that were received during a specific day.

Here is what I have:

```
select * from [Table Name]  WHERE received_when(column name) like '2015-08-02%'
```

Here are the column results when I do a `select * from [Table Name]`

2015-08-02 22:33:11.337
2015-08-02 22:33:57.243 
2015-08-02 22:49:49.617 
2015-08-02 22:50:34.600 
2015-08-02 22:50:52.493 
2015-08-02 22:51:12.600 
2015-08-02 22:51:35.007

I have used this query several times on other tables but for some reason this is returning 0 rows.  Thank you, Emley

Comment: What is the type of the column 'received_when'?

Answer (score 0):

If your `received_when` column is a datetime, then you will not be able to reliably query against it using a `LIKE` operator.

Try this instead

```
select * from [Table Name] WHERE received_when >= '2015-08-02' and received_when < '2015-08-03'
```

That will get everything that falls on the 8-2-2015 date

**EDIT**

[Working SQL Fiddle of example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5cd0a/2)

Comment: I think this will not work because the dates include hour, seconds and minutes

Comment: Good catch @miguelbgouveia. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: That is why I used the % after the 2.  The above did not work.

Comment: @Gastroconsults please see my edit for an SQL fiddle of this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what type `received_when` is, but I'm guessing it's either a `date` or a `datetime`. Treating it as a varchar (e.g., using the `like` operator) will implicitly convert it to one, and you shouldn't rely on the format you'd get. Instead, you should **explicitly** convert it

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [Table Name]
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, [received_when], 105) = '02-08-2015'
```

Comment: That worked!. Thank you.  I was then able to play with it and alter the date formate to 126 to do yyyy-mm and another on for the day.